# SQL - Column value manipulation -return dataset

Tags: sql-server

I have column values = 1,2,3 AND 0,1 across 2 records.

When selecting both records from a view I am trying to remove the '1,' and '1'

My attempt is below;

```
CAST(CASE WHEN (column like '%1%') THEN (ReturnTheValueWithout 1 OR 1,) 
ELSE column END AS VARCHAR) AS NewColumnName
```

Comment: The (ReturnTheValueWithout 1 OR 1,) is just a comment, I cannot figure out what can go in there. That is the main problem.

Comment: The column value can only reach to 3 -------------- I.E (0,1,2,3) is its max.

Comment: Does it always begin from 0? `0`, `0,1`, `0,1,2`, `0,1,2,3`?

Comment: No, can be anything, like 2,3, 1,2, 0,1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(column,'1,','')),',1','')
FROM TableName
```

Result:

```
2,3
0
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c94575/3).

Comment: Try with '1,11,2,1,3,4,1'

Comment: Output is 12,3,4, lost 11

Comment: Try your solution with `'0,12,31,2'`

Comment: Selecting the above as the right answer for my case as the column value can only reach to 3 ------- I.E (0,1,2,3) is its max.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1:**

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(20) = '1,11,2,1,3,4,1'
SELECT  REPLACE(CASE WHEN LEFT(@s, 2) = '1,'
                          AND RIGHT(@s, 2) = ',1'
                     THEN SUBSTRING(@s, 3, LEN(@s) - 4)
                     WHEN LEFT(@s, 2) = '1,' THEN RIGHT(@s, LEN(@s) - 2)
                     WHEN RIGHT(@s, 2) = ',1' THEN LEFT(@s, LEN(@s) - 2)
                     ELSE @s
                END, ',1,', ',')
```

Output:

```
11,2,3,4
```

**Solution2:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(',' + @s + ',', ',1,', ','), 2, LEN(REPLACE(',' + @s + ',', ',1,', ','))-2)
```

Shorter version:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(s, 2, LEN(s) - 2) FROM (SELECT REPLACE(',' + @s + ',', ',1,', ',') s)t
```

**Solution3:**

Most short:

```
SELECT REPLACE(',' + REPLACE(@s, ',1,', ',,1,') + ',', ',1,', '')
```

**Solution4:**

Above solutions failed here and there on some complex string. The following works on

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(120) = '1,31,11,2,1,3,4,1234,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,sfds,23,12,11,1'

SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE WHEN LEFT(@s, 2) = '1,'
                          AND RIGHT(@s, 2) = ',1'
                     THEN SUBSTRING(@s, 3, LEN(@s) - 4)
                     WHEN LEFT(@s, 2) = '1,' THEN RIGHT(@s, LEN(@s) - 2)
                     WHEN RIGHT(@s, 2) = ',1' THEN LEFT(@s, LEN(@s) - 2)
                     ELSE @s
                END, ',1,', ',,1,,'), ',1,', ''), ',,', ',')
```

Output:

```
31,11,2,3,4,1234,sfds,23,12,11
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using `REPLACE` with other string functions like `LEFT` and `STUFF`

**Query**

```
SELECT LEFT(STUFF(REPLACE(',' + Col1 + ',',',1,',','),1,1,''),LEN(STUFF(REPLACE(',' + Col1 + ',',',1,',','),1,1,''))-1)
```

**Test Script**

```
DECLARE @v varchar(50)  = '1,2,3'

--SET @v = '0,1'
SELECT LEFT(STUFF(REPLACE(',' + @v + ',',',1,',','),1,1,''),LEN(STUFF(REPLACE(',' + @v + ',',',1,',','),1,1,''))-1)
```

**Output**

```
0
2,3
```

**Edit**

A shorter version with `REVERSE`

```
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(STUFF(REPLACE(',' + Col1  + ',',',1,',','),1,1,'')),1,1,''))
FROM...
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06682/1)